# Pine script error "Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function."

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

Hi i was trying to uptdate a scrit and i got the is message "Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function." and i dont know how to fix it. can someone help me?

the error is on line 43, "ha_close = security(ha_t, timeframe.period, nAMA)"

thanks

```
//@version=4
strategy("Heikin/Kaufman Strategy ",shorttitle="HAS/KAU",overlay=true,max_bars_back=500,default_qty_value = 100,initial_capital = 100,default_qty_type = strategy.cash, commission_value=0.1)
res1 = input(title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame", type=input.resolution, defval="D")
test = input(0,"Heikin Ashi EMA Shift")
sloma = input(20,"Slow EMA Period")



Length = input(6, minval=1)
xPrice = close
xvnoise = abs(xPrice - xPrice[1])
nAMA = 0.0
nfastend = input(0.56,  minval = 0.05, step = 0.01)
nslowend = input(0.28,  minval = 0.05, step = 0.01)
nsignal = abs(xPrice - xPrice[Length])
nnoise = sum(xvnoise, Length)
nefratio = iff(nnoise != 0, nsignal / nnoise, 0)
nsmooth = pow(nefratio * (nfastend - nslowend) + nslowend, 2) 
nAMA := nz(nAMA[1]) + nsmooth * (xPrice - nz(nAMA[1]))
plot(nAMA, color=color.blue, title="KAMA")


//Heikin Ashi Open/Close Price
ha_t = heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
ha_close = security(ha_t, timeframe.period, nAMA)
mha_close = security(ha_t, res1, hlc3)


//Moving Average
fma = ema(mha_close[test],1)
sma = ema(ha_close,sloma)
plot(fma,title="MA",color=color.black,linewidth=2)
plot(sma,title="SMA",color=color.red,linewidth=2)


//Strategy
golong =  crossover(fma,sma) 
goshort =   crossunder(fma,sma)

strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long,when = golong) 
strategy.entry("Sell",strategy.short,when = goshort)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move all your calculations related to the variable you want to use as `expression` in the `security()` call in a function and call that function in the `security()` call.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Heikin/Kaufman Strategy ",shorttitle="HAS/KAU",overlay=true,max_bars_back=500,default_qty_value = 100,initial_capital = 100,default_qty_type = strategy.cash, commission_value=0.1)
res1 = input(title="Heikin Ashi EMA Time Frame", type=input.resolution, defval="D")
test = input(0,"Heikin Ashi EMA Shift")
sloma = input(20,"Slow EMA Period")



Length = input(6, minval=1)
nfastend = input(0.56,  minval = 0.05, step = 0.01)
nslowend = input(0.28,  minval = 0.05, step = 0.01)


f_get_nAMA() =>
    nAMA = 0.0
    xPrice = close
    xvnoise = abs(xPrice - xPrice[1])
    nsignal = abs(xPrice - xPrice[Length])
    nnoise = sum(xvnoise, Length)
    nefratio = iff(nnoise != 0, nsignal / nnoise, 0)
    nsmooth = pow(nefratio * (nfastend - nslowend) + nslowend, 2) 
    nAMA := nz(nAMA[1]) + nsmooth * (xPrice - nz(nAMA[1]))

plot(f_get_nAMA(), color=color.blue, title="KAMA")


//Heikin Ashi Open/Close Price
ha_t = heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
ha_close = security(ha_t, timeframe.period, f_get_nAMA())
mha_close = security(ha_t, res1, hlc3)


//Moving Average
fma = ema(mha_close[test],1)
sma = ema(ha_close,sloma)
plot(fma,title="MA",color=color.black,linewidth=2)
plot(sma,title="SMA",color=color.red,linewidth=2)


//Strategy
golong =  crossover(fma,sma) 
goshort =   crossunder(fma,sma)

strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long,when = golong) 
strategy.entry("Sell",strategy.short,when = goshort)
```